# VueJS Autocomplete with array of objects

Tags: autocomplete, vuejs2

I try to modifiy an autocomplete component from a component I found on github and I have a problem for display my values

Here is my Autocomplete.vue

```
 <template>
  <div style="position:relative" v-bind:class="{'open':openSuggestion}">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" :value="value" @input="updateValue($event.target.value)"
           @keydown.enter='enter'
           @keydown.down='down'
           @keydown.up='up'
    >
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
      <li v-for="(suggestion, index) in matches"
          v-bind:class="{'active': isActive(index)}"
          @click="suggestionClick(index)"
      >
        <a href="#">{{ suggestion.name }}
          <small>{{ suggestion.id}}</small>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      value: {
        //type: Object,
        required: true
      },
      suggestions: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        open: false,
        current: 0
      }
    },
    computed: {
      // Filtering the suggestion based on the input
      matches () {
        return this.suggestions.filter((obj) => {
          return obj.name.indexOf(this.value) >= 0
        })
      },
      openSuggestion () {
        return this.selection !== '' &&
          this.matches.length !== 0 &&
          this.open === true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateValue (value) {
        if (this.open === false) {
          this.open = true
          this.current = 0
        }
        this.$emit('input', value)
      },
      // When enter pressed on the input
      enter () {
        this.$emit('input', this.matches[this.current])
        this.open = false
      },
      // When up pressed while suggestions are open
      up () {
        if (this.current > 0) {
          this.current--
        }
      },
      // When up pressed while suggestions are open
      down () {
        if (this.current < this.matches.length - 1) {
          this.current++
        }
      },
      // For highlighting element
      isActive (index) {
        return index === this.current
      },
      // When one of the suggestion is clicked
      suggestionClick (index) {
        this.$emit('input', this.matches[index])
        this.open = false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And I use my component like this :

```
 <autocomplete :suggestions="allBranchesEconomiquesActives" v-model="modifiedElementRegistre.personneMorale.brancheEconomique"></autocomplete>
```

Where *allBranchesEconomiquesActives* is an array of objects:

```
[
{code:"A"
id:1
isActif:true
name:"Branche1"},
{code:"B"
id:2
isActif:true
name:"Branche2"},
....
]
```

and *modifiedElementRegistre.personneMorale.brancheEconomique* my model

My problem is my input display "[object Object]" when I pick an element from my suggestions list. And if I put ":value="value.name" in my input, I can't write in the input, the value is always reset (only the last typed character stay)

How can I do to have my object in my model and displayed correctly in my input ?

Comment: What do you mean by autocomplete? It seems like select with search results as options.

Comment: Yes, it's juste an input with a list of suggestions. The <li> containing suggestions works fine but when I select an item, my input show [Object Object]. I'll try to give a fiddle when I have the time

Answer (score 0):

Your input shows `[Object Object]`, because you give to it whole Object, while String is expected.
To be able to edit value of `<input>`, you can copy the name of your `value` property and use `v-model` with that copy. Reset copy value to initial/new as required.

```
<template>
  <div style="position:relative" v-bind:class="{'open':openSuggestion}">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"
           v-model="text"
           @input="updateValue($event.target.value)"
           @keydown.enter='enter'
           @keydown.down='down'
           @keydown.up='up'
           @blur='resetText'
    >
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
      <li v-for="(suggestion, index) in matches"
          v-bind:class="{'active': isActive(index)}"
          @click="suggestionClick(index)"
      >
        <a href="#">{{ suggestion.name }}
          <small>{{ suggestion.id}}</small>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      value: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      },
      suggestions: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        text: "",
        open: false,
        current: 0
      }
    },
    computed: {
      // Filtering the suggestion based on the input
      matches () {
        return this.suggestions.filter((obj) => {
          return obj.name.indexOf(this.text) >= 0
        })
      },
      openSuggestion () {
        return this.selection !== '' &&
          this.matches.length !== 0 &&
          this.open === true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateValue (value) {
        if (this.open === false) {
          this.open = true
          this.current = 0
        }
      },
      // When enter pressed on the input
      enter () {
        this.$emit('input', this.matches[this.current])
        this.open = false
      },
      // When up pressed while suggestions are open
      up () {
        if (this.current > 0) {
          this.current--
        }
      },
      // When up pressed while suggestions are open
      down () {
        if (this.current < this.matches.length - 1) {
          this.current++
        }
      },
      // For highlighting element
      isActive (index) {
        return index === this.current
      },
      // When one of the suggestion is clicked
      suggestionClick (index) {
        this.$emit('input', this.matches[index])
        this.open = false
      },
      resetText() {
        this.text = this.value.name;
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.text = this.value.name;
    },
    watch: {
      value() {
        this.text = this.value.name;
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Also, it seems that emitting event `this.$emit('input', value)` when typing is excess.